# Error en un Cursor

Tags: android

Tengo una sentencia:

```
final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapterLocal = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, equipolocal);
equilocalspiner.setAdapter(arrayAdapterLocal);
equilocalspiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Selecionar equipo Local
        NombreEquipoLocal = (String) equilocalspiner.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        //Toast.makeText(MainJornadas.this, NombreEquipoLocal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        FSDbHelper dbhelperequilocal = new FSDbHelper(MainJornadas.this);
        SQLiteDatabase databaseequlocal = dbhelperequilocal.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursorequil = databaseequlocal.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + InContract.EquiposColumnas.TABLA_EQUIPOS
                                + " WHERE " + InContract.EquiposColumnas.EQUIPO + " = " + NombreEquipoLocal, null);
        CodigoEquipoLocal = cursorequil.getInt(InContract.EquiposColumnas.IDEQUI_INDEX);
         String lll = String.valueOf(cursorequil.getInt(InContract.EquiposColumnas.IDEQUI_INDEX));
         Toast.makeText(MainJornadas.this, NombreEquipoLocal + " --> " + lll, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
         cursorequil.close();
         databaseequlocal.close();
         dbhelperequilocal.close();
     }
     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
     }
});
```

Y al ejecutarlo sale un error en la sentencia del Cursor cursorequil .....
este es el error:

```
 at com.valhondo.delgado.fsmerida.jornadas.MainJornadas$4.onItemSelected(MainJornadas.java:373)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:53)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

> 2020-01-08 13:53:07.040 1786-2377/? E/ActivityTrigger:
>   activityResumeTrigger: not
>   whiteListedcom.valhondo.delgado.fsmerida/com.valhondo.delgado.fsmerida.MainActivity/1
>   2020-01-08 13:53:07.041 587-659/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile
>   no. 0, total profiles 0 only 2020-01-08 13:53:09.709 559-1241/?
>   E/soundtrigger: audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: invalid
>   input device 0x0, for event 2

Comment: ademas del stacktrace tambien te deberia mostrar un "caused by..." podrias subirlo todo? e indicar cual es la linea 373 dentro de tu codigo.

Comment: Lo que agregas del LogCat no es de mucha ayuda, agrega lo que comenta Erick, el mensaje que inicia con "Caused by", saludos.